# <f:ajax> listener not working in nested <p:overlayPanel>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, overlay

I have nested overlay panels inside nested datatables. In the code below ajax is not working properly. The same ajax call work sometimes and does not work next time. Sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it does not.

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="MultipleDataTable"
    var="MultipleDiseasedDetail"
    rendered="#{diseasePatientDetailController.radioButtonSelect == 2}"
    value="#{diseasePatientDetailController.groupedMultiDiseasedPatientsByDiseaseIdList}"
    scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="235"
    rows="20"
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
    paginatorPosition="bottom"
    style="float:left;width:500px;"
    >

    <p:column styleClass="DiseaseNameTableColumn" sortBy="#{MultipleDiseasedDetail.disease_Name}">                                                    
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Diseases"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink id="patient" value="#{MultipleDiseasedDetail.disease_Name}">
            <f:param id="diseaseIdParam" name="diseaseIdParam" value="#{MultipleDiseasedDetail.disease_Id}"/>
            <f:ajax 
                listener="#{diseasePatientDetailController.MultiDataTable_RowClickEvent}"
                execute ="patient diseaseIdParam"
                event="click"                                        
                render ="drDiseasesByCountTable"                                        
                />
        </h:commandLink>
        <p:overlayPanel
            id="MultipleDiseasePanel"
            appendToBody="true"
            for="patient"
            hideEffect="fade"
            dynamic="true"
            style="width:600px"
            showCloseIcon="true"
            >
            <p:dataTable 
                id="drDiseasesByCountTable"
                var="drDiseasesByCount"
                value="#{diseasePatientDetailController.groupedMultiDiseasedPatientsByDiseaseGroupList}"
                scrollable="true"
                scrollHeight="175"
                rows="20"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
                paginatorPosition="bottom"
                >

                <p:column styleClass="DiseaseNameTableColumn" sortBy="#{drDiseasesByCount.grp_disease_names}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Diseases"/>                                        
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink id="groupedDiseasesLink" value="#{drDiseasesByCount.grp_disease_names}">                                        
                        <f:param id="grpDiseaseIdsParam" name="grpDiseaseIdsParam" value="#{drDiseasesByCount.grp_disease_ids}"/>                                                  
                        <f:ajax 
                            listener="#{diseasePatientDetailController.drDiseasesByCountTable_RowClickEvent}"
                            execute ="groupedDiseasesLink grpDiseaseIdsParam"
                            event="click"
                            render="groupedDiseasesPatientsTable"
                            />
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <p:overlayPanel 
                        id="MultipleDiseasePatientPanel"
                        appendToBody="true"
                        for="groupedDiseasesLink"
                        hideEffect="fade"
                        dismissable="false" 
                        showCloseIcon="true"
                        dynamic="true" 
                        style="width:600px">

                        <p:dataTable 
                            id="groupedDiseasesPatientsTable"
                            var="drGroupPatient"
                            value="#{diseasePatientDetailController.multiPatientsByGroupDiseaseIDList}"
                            scrollable="true"
                            scrollHeight="150"
                            rows="20"
                            paginator="true"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom"
                            >

                            <p:column styleClass="DiseaseNameTableColumn" sortBy="#{drGroupPatient.patientName}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Patient"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputLink value="#{drGroupPatient.patientDashboardUrl}">
                                    <h:outputText id="patient" value="#{drGroupPatient.patientName}" />
                                </h:outputLink>                                            
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:overlayPanel>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Am I doing anything wrong with the ajax call. I have well tested my backend controllers. They are working fine. Is it not a good practice to work with overlaypanel with nested datatables.

Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Can you try using `p:ajax` instead of `f:ajax` to see what happens?

Comment: Awesome, It works!! That was the only edit that I missed in my hit and trial. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the complete answer, your `f:ajax` should go from

```
<f:ajax
  listener="#{diseasePatientDetailController.MultiDataTable_RowClickEvent}"
  execute ="patient diseaseIdParam"
  event="click"                                        
  render ="drDiseasesByCountTable"/>
```

to

```
<p:ajax
  listener="#{diseasePatientDetailController.MultiDataTable_RowClickEvent}"
  process="patient diseaseIdParam"
  event="click"                                        
  update="drDiseasesByCountTable"/>
```